# Resetting a bought used iPad 2

Tags: ipad, icloud, find-my-iphone

I'm buying a used iPad 2 through Craigslist.  He has lost his iCloud account info for that iPad 2. If he does a factory reset on the iPad 2 and I bought it after reset, would it be possible during set up.

Can I use my own iCloud info to go forward and pass through, on the set up of the iPad 2 once I bought it from that person?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if he signed out of his iCloud account and turned off Find my iPad first. iOS has a built-in feature so that a thief cannot wipe a device and login with his own credentials. If he *did* log out, then you will be fine. If he *didn't*, he should go to iCloud.com and reset his password if he does not know his credentials.  From there, he can turn off Find my iPad remotely so you can login. If you cannot set up the iPad, and he does not perform these steps, you will not be able to use the iPad.